# How to shift odoo website from locahost to live server without restoring complete database?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-website

A client has a live website with data and he just want to upgrade the website design, without effecting the live data. He asked me to build website on a local server or a a different instance on same hosting and then shift that design to the live instance.

Answer (score 0):

With Odoo you can build the website as an own extensions and build all the content / design part with the xml/qweb templates. So yes, you build up the extension and then just upload this extension on the server and install it there.